# Symfony DI for Event classes

Tags: php, symfony, events, dependency-injection

I have some events in my project that uses DI. When my events are an instance of App\Manager\ValidatorAwareInterface I configure then to inject the @validator service.

When I have this code in the services.yaml it works :

```
services:
    _instanceof:
        App\Manager\Validator\ValidatorAwareInterface:
            calls:
                -   method: setValidator
                    arguments:
                        - '@validator'
```

But when I put this same code in a manager.yaml file that I import in the services.yaml, it does not work anymore :

```
imports:
    - { resource: manager.yaml }
```

Do you have an idea why ?

Thanks.

Comment: What error occurs when you call this service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should copy symfony's default service configuration in your manager.yaml before defining others services since the default configuration is only applied to the services defined in that file. [The new Default services.yaml File](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#the-new-default-services-yaml-file)

```
# config/manager.yaml
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

Answer (score 5):

@stephan.mada's answer will probably fix your problem.

But I would like to point out a little known annotation called '@required' which eliminates the need to explicitly configure your setter at all.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

trait ValidatorTrait
{
    /** @var ValidatorInterface */
    protected $validator;

    /** @required */
    public function injectValidator(ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $this->validator ?: $validator;
    }
}
```

The '@required' before the inject method causes the container to automatically inject the dependency.  Your setter stuff in services.yaml can go away completely.  You don't see a whole lot of usage of '@required' but it does come in handy for commonly injected services.

You might also notice that I used a trait here.  With a trait, I no longer need a base class or interface.  Any service that uses the trait will automatically get the validator service injected.  You can of course just use a conventional class if you like.

```
class SomeService
{
    use ValidatorTrait; // And the validator is now available
    use RouterTrait;    // As well as the router
```

And one final note.  I added a guard to ensure that the validator can only be injected once.  This protects against rogue programmers who might be tempted to inject a different validator at some other point in the cycle.

Comment: Is it compatible with Symfony 2.8 ? I would like to use it on an old project

Comment: I have no idea if it will work on 2.8.  I suspect not but try it and let us know.