# Can traits have services injected?

Tags: symfony, traits

In my Symfony 4.4 project I want to add specific method every time I trigger setSomething() setter method, but perhaps I can use traits?

Can traits have services injected?

Comment: Yes you can automatically inject services into traits using the @required annotation.  [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56005984/symfony-di-for-event-classes/56006588#56006588).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but it's not injected automatically like autowiring in services.
Here's an example i made with TranslatorInterface injected in my service and use in my trait :

```php
trait MyTrait
{
    private TranslatorInterface $translator;

    public function setTranslator(TranslatorInterface $translator): self
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
        return $this;
    }

    public functio myTraitFunction()
    {
        // use $this->translator
    } 
}

class MyClass
{
    use MyTrait;


    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
       $this->setTranslator($translator);
    }

    public function somFunction(): something
    {
        // use $this->myTraitFunction()
    }

}
```

EDIT: Cerad's solution is better than mine above, check it on [Symfony DI for Event classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56005984/symfony-di-for-event-classes/56006588#56006588) and prefer use of `@required` annotation

Comment: Consider looking at my comment on the original question.  Symfony does support automatically injecting services into traits.  Whether you should or not is a different question but doing so eliminates some boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, maybe useful for future readers. If you have a trait based on a service, or on class member, I would go for an abstract method like

```
trait MyTrait
{
  protected abstract function getTranslator(): TranslatorInterface;
  [...]
}
```

and then implement the method inside the class that uses the trait.

Personally I would prefer not to depend on "setter injection" and bound two methods that are only logically coupled.

If you embrace this, the question is not actually a question as you can inject service in the canonical way.

Comment: Just little question, make abstract function in trait is not for PHP 8 ?

Comment: @Hamham only for `private`. Check those out: 1) https://3v4l.org/n8kgV 2) https://3v4l.org/ffcVm and 3) https://3v4l.org/mlq6g